# how can I grab the div id from the following return?

Tags: jquery, variables

[image]

The following code returns the above.

```
var b = $(c).parent();
```

The div id is a color code, when the user clicks to a new section, the jQuery updates a background color. I need to return just the color code of the Id?

I'am sure the answer is embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Can we see some more code and the associated HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the ID you can use jQuery's `attr()` method: [[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)]:

```
var bId = $(c).parent().attr("id");
```

Or you could get at the raw DOM element and grab the ID:

```
var bId = $(c).parent().get(0).id
//OR
var bId = $(c).parent()[0].id
```

Comment: You *can*, though the ID is technically a property, so you should use the `.prop()` function instead. Or you could get the actual element, and access the ID directly - `$(c).parent()[0].id`. Both are preferable to using `.attr()`.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried the .id but I didn't realize I needed to add [0].